# ffmpeg syntax has changed

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-12.04, libx264

Just like what was talked about in this post: [FFmpeg cannot recognize a preset even though it does exsist Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836888/ffmpeg-cannot-recognize-a-preset-even-though-it-does-exsist-ubuntu-12-04)

I have help, with **deblockalpha** which has been depreciated from ffmpeg for along time,
i am no good with all this coding business, but would like someone to tell me how i can fix this outdated syntax, as i am getting this error:

*Unrecognized option 'deblockalpha'
Failed to set value '0' for option 'deblockalpha'*

please see code below and advise?

```
$ffmpeg -i $input -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -s 512x288 -aspect 16:9 -b 1550k -maxrate 1800k -bufsize 4M -bt 1600k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -deblockalpha 0 -deblockbeta 0 -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_method full -me_range 16 -subq 5 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp8x8 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -level 30 -trellis 2 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -ar 44100 -ac 2 $addpre $output";
```

thanks

Comment: Please include the complete ffmpeg console output.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `-deblockalpha 0 -deblockbeta 0` with `-deblock 0:0`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `-deblockalpha 0` from your command.